# RewriteRule is not working correctly, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

The rewriterule that I am using on localhost works the way I want it to work, but when I upload it to the server, it just doesn't anymore.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
```

Locally it gives the desired url, localhost/links/ ... But as soon as it's on the server, I get this: [www.domain.com/index.php?url=links/](http://www.domain.com/index.php?url=links/)

I don't understand why that is... and is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, thanks AI...

Simply put, I just needed to add:

```
RewriteBase /
```

The only downside is that on localhost it redirects me to http://localhost/, but it works on the server.